# The number of librarians among $210$ people (how to explain this mathematically)

Tags: probability, statistics

I was watching 3blue1brown's video on the Bayes theorem, and I really like the way he explains the subject, but there was one point I would like to clarify.

Let's say we know (somehow) that there are $20$ farmers per each librarian. We consider some more or less representative sample of $210$ people and argue that there will be $210 \times \frac{1}{21} = 10$ librarians and $210 \times \frac{20}{21} = 200$ farmers.

That makes sense intuitively that if we know statistics on the distribution of farmers and librarians then for a big enough sample we can just multiply the number of people by the corresponding probabilities.

But how do we argue about that more formally? This is similar to the question that asks about the most likely number of heads/tails for $100$ trials and a fair coin. I know that getting $50$ heads is the most likely outcome (the probability $\approx 0.08$). We also know that the expectation of the binomial distribution equals $np$.

That said, saying that there are on average $20$ times more farmers than librarians seems a bit different to me. Isn't that somehow related to the statistical definition of probability? Is there any formal justification for saying that we expect there to be $10$ farmers among $210$ random people?

Thank you!
[image: Screenshot from the video, see the number of people in the formula]

Comment: To clarify, $20$ farmers per each librarian... and we get $210$ people.  For your discussion to make sense... these $210$ people must have necessarily all been selected from the combined pool of farmers and librarians without bias and nowhere in there did we select any musicians or hockey players or clowns or any other profession...

Comment: Are you, perhaps, looking for the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)?

Comment: @JMoravitz, I guess that in that video the claim is exactly what you wrote. That might not sound very plausible, but let's say the sample is representative.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you for your answer. Yes, I am familiar with the law of big numbers. I am just wondering if that way of thinking is applicable when we just have some sample and we know some piece of information (like the one about librarians/farmers). Such type of reasoning is very common, but it seems to me that there's way too much simplification in it.

Comment: As an aside, among $5$ people, *the expected number* of librarians would have been $\frac{5}{21}$.  That is not to say that we expect that among five people there can be found a disembodied torso of a librarian., just that if we were to select five people repeatedly, and take the average number of librarians seen within those samples (*so averaging several zeros, some ones, a few twos, even fewer threes, etc..*) that the average comes out to $\frac{5}{21}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes, I understand that. Can you please take a look at the screenshot I have just added to the post? That's what I was referring to? There is "the number of people = $210$) in the formula multiplied by $P(H)$ and $P(E|H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we know that there are exactly $20$ times as many farmers as librarians in the population. Moreover suppose we have a way to randomly pick someone from the population, guaranteed to be either a farmer or a librarian, in which every person who is either a farmer or librarian is as likely to be chosen as any other.

We now select a sample of $210$ persons.

The first person selected for the sample has a $\frac1{21}$ probability to be a librarian, and a $\frac{20}{21}$ probability to be a farmer.
We can work this out by taking the number of librarians, $L$, the number of farmers, $20L$, and the probability that any particular individual will be selected, $\frac1{L + 20L}.$ There are $L$ disjoint events in which we select a librarian, total probability $\frac L{L + 20L},$
and $20L$ disjoint events in which we select a farmer,
total probability $\frac {20L}{L + 20L}.$

If the selection process were with replacement, so that the same person could be selected again, the distribution of librarians would just be a binomial distribution and its expected value would be $np$ (as you know).

A more reasonable assumption is that the selection is done without replacement,
so the distribution is not binomial.
But the probability for the $k$th-selected person to be a librarian is still $\frac1{21}$. You can argue this by symmetry (no person could be more likely to be the $k$th-selected than any other), or you can work out the probability for each person that they are one of the first $k-1$ selections (with zero probability to be the $k$th-selected, conditioned on that event)
and the probability that they are not among the first $k-1$ persons selected,
multiplied by the probability that they are selected on the $k$th selection conditioned on the fact that $k-1$ other people were previously selected (which is slightly higher than $\frac1{21}$ since the total population is slightly smaller).

Likewise the $k$th-selected person is a farmer with probability $\frac{20}{21}$.

Now for $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 210,$ let $X_k = 1$ if the $k$th-selected person is a librarian, $X_k = 0$ if they are a farmer.
The number of librarians in the sample then is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{210} X_k.$$
The expected value of $X_k$ for each $k$ is
$$ E(X_k) = \frac1{21}.$$

Therefore, by linearity of expectation,
$$ E\left( \sum_{k=1}^{210} X_k\right)
= \sum_{k=1}^{210} E(X_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{210} \frac1{21} = 10. $$

Of course the variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are not independent, but linearity of expectation has nothing to do with independence.
The expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations regardless.

And that is why we expect $10$ librarians.
A similar argument shows we expect $200$ farmers,
or you can just subtract the $10$ expected librarians from the $210$ expected persons in the sample.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll say something about it and we can see it it addresses the matter.

Suppose everyone is either a farmer or a librarian. Suppose you pick $210$ members of this population of farmers and librarians at random in such a way that everyone has an equal chance of being chosen.

Now an issue arises: Do we $(1)$ take care to make sure no individual is chosen twice?, or $(2)$ is each choice independent of the others? If this population of farmers and librarians consists of $100\,000\,000$ persons, then getting the same person twice, if that is allowed, is so highly improbable that there is no practical difference between $(1)$ and $(2).$ But if there are only $210$ persons, then there is a great difference, because we could only get exactly $200$ farmers and $10$ librarians.

Regardless of whether we follow option $(1)$ or option $(2),$ on **average** we would get $200$ farmers and $10$ librarians. If the random variable $X$ is the number of farmers in this sample then its expected value is $\operatorname E(X)=200.$ If we follow option $(2)$ then the standard deviation of $X$ is $\operatorname{sd}(X) = \sqrt{210\times\frac{200}{210} \times \frac{10}{210}}.$ If we follow option $(1)$ then the standard deviation can be made as close to that as we want by making the whole population big enough (thus with $100\,000\,000$ persons in the population, for all practical purposes the standard deviation is as big as the number mentioned above). With option $(1)$ the standard deviation gets smaller as the population gets smaller, and, as mentioned above, the standard deviation is $0$ when the population is only $210.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

"Regardless of whether we follow option (1) or option (2), on average we would get 200 farmers and 10 librarians." 

That just follows from our knowledge of the expectation of a binomially distributed random variable, right? And is this conclusion related to the law of big numbers?

Comment: By the way, did you mean to multiply by $210$ when calculating the $sd(X)$?

Comment: @DonDraper : I did, but even more important is that I forgot the $\sqrt{\text{radical}}. \qquad$

Comment: @DonDraper : With independent sampling, i.e. WITH replacement, it's binomial. Without replacement, it's hypergeometric rather than binomial.